# Joining two tables with a third unrelated table

Tags: sql-server

I have two relaled product tables and a third unrelated period table that I want to use to make sure I get a full set of data returned.

I don't want to store all of the empty periods for every product, just the periods that get a sale.

First, we have the financials table, which is the 'master' of all the periods:

```
ID | PERIOD
------------
1  | Jan
2  | Feb
3  | Mar
```

Then the product and sales tables

```
ID | Code
------------
1  | ABC
2  | XYZ

Product_ID | Period_ID | Sales
------------------------------
    1      |     1     |    5
    2      |     1     |    4
    2      |     3     |    7
```

I would like to formulate a query so that I can return the results for each of the periods, regardless of whether they have sales or not:

```
Product_ID | Product_Code | Period_ID | Period_Name | Sales
-----------------------------------------------------------
    1      |     ABC      |     1     |    Jan      |   5
    1      |     ABC      |     2     |    Feb      |   0
    1      |     ABC      |     3     |    Mar      |   0 
    2      |     XYZ      |     1     |    Jan      |   4
    2      |     XYZ      |     2     |    Feb      |   0 
    2      |     XYZ      |     3     |    Mar      |   7
```

I need the query to be as generic as possible, it will need to work against Firebird (1.5) and MS SQL. If that's not possible, then MS SQL is the preferred.

Secondary to this, if there was more then 1 entry in the sales table for a period, can the total be summed? ie:

```
Product_ID | Period_ID | Sales
------------------------------
    1      |     1     |    1
    1      |     1     |    1
```

Would return

```
Product_ID | Period_ID | Sales
------------------------------
    1      |     1     |    4
```

for that specific line.

I have tried to do a join, but I can't see how to get it to join the information from the period table for each product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` `Financial` table and `Product` table first to get all possible combinations of period and product. Then do a `LEFT JOIN` and `SUM` on `Sales` to get the desired result:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6e371/2/0)

```
SELECT
    p.ID AS Product_ID,
    p.Code AS Product_Code,
    f.ID AS Period_ID,
    f.Period AS Period_ID,
    SUM(COALESCE(s.Sales, 0)) AS Sales
FROM Financials f
CROSS JOIN Product p
LEFT JOIN Sales s
    ON s.Period_ID = f.ID
    AND s.Product_ID = p.ID
GROUP BY
    p.ID, p.Code, f.ID, f.Period
ORDER BY
    p.ID, f.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work for MS SQL. Firebird 1.5 doesn't have the CROSS JOIN command, is there a more agnostic way of doing this? Also what would be the best index optimisation for this, it runs quite slow the first time.

Comment: Instead of `CROSS JOIN` try: `FROM Financials f, Product p`.

Comment: Or `FROM Financials f INNER JOIN Product p ON 1 = 1`

Comment: Thanks the second one works perfectly, it actually ran faster but had a much more convoluted execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join. Something like

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM master AS a LEFT JOIN sales AS b ON (a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID)
```

Comment: Sorry, this only joins the product and sales table and ignores the missing periods.